# Washing machine dumps detergent

Tags: washing-machine

I have a top loading washing machine in which I use liquid detergent. It has a receptacle on the inner side of the lid for different kinds of detergents (pre-wash, wash, rinsing agent) which would then be released when appropriate. But then I noticed that both the pre-wash and wash containers get dumped out onto the drum as I close the lid. Is this by design? Why are then separate containers?

Comment: Also, sorry if off-topic, I can't think of a better SE site to post this on.

Comment: I believe this is off topic since it appears to be about the operation of an appliance. But it's close enough to a repair question that I'm not willing to cast a binding vote just yet. I don't know of any other SE where this would be on topic, but that doesn't mean the question must be on topic here.